# MinGW gcj compiler not found by MinGW shell

Tags: java, compiler-construction, mingw

I tried to compile a simple Java class with gcj, but I'm getting this error: "sh: gcj: command not found". I installed it according to those tutorials:
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW

To fix this problem I added all relevant MinGW paths to the user PATH variable:
C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\local\bin;C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin

This also didn't fix the problem. What might have gone wrong here? Thanks for any help.

The installation file is "mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe", I'm using Windows 7 64 Bit.

Comment: gcj : Have you build it, or where have you download it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get GCJ through official mingw website since they dont develop it anymore. But there a download here: http://www.thisiscool.com/gcc_mingw.htm

Answer (score 0):

I download mingw-get-setup.exe

https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/

and select from a window; gcj compiler.

This executable install all that you want and you select; the compiler to Fortran, Ada, Objetive C, and Java.